# Dll missing in mono project with Xamarin on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono

Hi I am new to C# and Mono. I want to compile a [project](https://github.com/proletariatgames/haxe-cslibgen) from github. After downloading Xamarin(on Windows 10) says it can't find Mono.Cecil.dll. The .csproj file says

Reference Include="Mono.Cecil, Version=0.9.4.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756"

I copied a random Mono.Cecil.dll of version 0.9.4.0 but it doesn't work (which has probably to do with the certificate). If you check the github site you see it's a tiny project, and it doesnt provide Mono.cecil.dll, which probably means there are easy steps. Yet I could not find on google any recent pointers how to deal with this.

How to proceed to get the right Mono.Cecil.dll and the right certificate?

Comment: Report the issue to the author and wait for an answer there. Asking others on SO to review of the code for you is out of scope of a fair question.

Comment: I don' see any explicit asking others to review code and neither was my intention to do that implicitly. And I did ask the author for help the project however seems abandoned, but like i said it probably means there are easy steps I am unaware of and cant find on google.

Comment: I included the only interesting description about the cecil assembly, code review isn't needed to an answer this question. Easy to see. I tried to be as specific as I could, which is why I included the link. There is not really much to review, which is very easy to verify before you start going out of reach yourself. And I did ask the author for help the project however seems abandoned, but like i said it probably means there are easy steps I am unaware of and cant find on google. I ask what I ask and nothing between the lines. Dont be negative when there really is no reason..